# Returns true average for all inputs. Parameters are all ints

Tags: java, int, double

I need help returning a double average without using double parameters. So far I have all ints but its returning an int. I need the true average which should be 2.66666666667

```
public class NumAvg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, c;
        double average;
        a = 5;
        b = 2;
        c = 1;
        average = findAverage(a, b, c);
        System.out.print(average);
    }
    public static double findAverage(int a, int b, int c) {
        double findAverage;
        findAverage = (a + b + c)/3;
        return findAverage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are performing Java's integer division, which must return another integer.  You can force floating point division by using a `double` literal or by casting one of the numbers to a `double`.  Specifying `findAverage` as a `double` is not enough.  Try

```
findAverage = (a + b + c) / 3.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
findAverage = (double) (a + b + c) / 3.0;
```

I don't really remember how it calls.

UPD: It calls "casting".

Answer (score 0):

Try casting your parameters to double. `findAverage = ( (double)( a + b + c ) )/3.0d;`

Answer (score 0):

just do:

```
findAverage = (double)(a + b + c)/3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to typecast all of the `int` numbers to `double`.

```
findAverage = ((double)a + (double)b + (double)c)/3;
```